# Check if type of next token is double, long or int without using JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

I need to read the JSON response from a `HttpURLConnection` using `JsonReader`. To find out what the type of the next token is, I used the [JsonReader.peek()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html#peek()) method, which returns a [JsonToken](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonToken.html). However, I have to differentiate if the next token is a Java `double`, `long` or `int` so that I can get the token using `JsonReader.next*()` methods, since `NUMBER` is returned if the next token is a Java `double`, `long` or `int`. The following is my code:

```
final Map<String, Object> results = new HashMap<>();

while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
    final String name = jsonReader.nextName();

    switch (jsonReader.peek()) {
        case BOOLEAN:
            results.put(name, jsonReader.nextBoolean());
            break;
        case NAME:
            results.put(name, jsonReader.nextName());
            break;
        case NULL:
            results.put(name, null);
            break;
        case NUMBER:
            // results.put(name, jsonReader.nextInt()); TODO: Find out how to differentiate between int, long and double
            break;
        case STRING:
            results.put(name, jsonReader.nextString());
            break;
        default:
            jsonReader.skipValue();
            break;
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to check if the type of next token is double, long or int without using JSONObject?

Comment: @David How do I do that? In try/catch blocks?

Comment: Object o = jsonReader.peek();   if (o instanceof JSONObject) { //do things }

Comment: @VaibhavKadam You can't, `o instanceof JSONObject` is always false

Comment: @marshmallow Object o = jsonReader.peek(); if (o instanceof Double) { //do things }

Comment: @VaibhavKadam You can't, because `jsonReader.peek()` returns `JsonToken`, not `Double`, etc.

Comment: You can almost 100% avoid the problem by just using double.  Why?  And int and a long are the same type, a long just can store larger numbers as well so you can ignore int.  ANd while not all longs fit in a double, anything smaller than 2^52 will fit exactly, which is almost always good enough.

Comment: `jshell> (long) (double) 9123456789123456789L` ==> `123456789123457024`
Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0):

You can read next number as a String using `nextString()` and `JsonReader` will return it without failing. Then, you can choose between `long` and `double` depending on whether this string contains `.`.